# Creating a progress bar using Canvas (Discord)

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, discord.js

I'm trying to create a command called !rank which shows the rank card with the level, the rank in the guild, the xp they have, the xp they need to level up and their name. I'm also trying to have a progress bar like MEE6 on the bottom. I have coded for the rest but can't seem to find the answer for the progress bar

Here is the main code :

```
         if(message.channel.id === '784491491435085865'){
        const colors = [0x00E2FF, 0x00FF85];
        const randomColorNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
        const randomColor = colors[randomColorNo];
 
        const nextLVL = Math.floor(user.level + 1);
        const XPNeeded = Levels.xpFor(nextLVL);

        const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./level.png');
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
       
        const percentage = Math.floor((userPosition.xp / XPNeeded) * 100);
        const roundedPercent = Math.round(percentage);

        var i;
        for(i = 0;i < roundedPercent; i++)  {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(170 + i, 170, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill(randomColor);
        }
        //Tryed to add a progress bar where it draws individual circles for each percentage but 
        //failed

        const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer('image/jpeg', { quality: 1 }), 'levelDisplay.png');

            
                message.channel.send(attachment);
        
         }
         else{
            message.reply('This command is only allowed in <#784491491435085865>');
         }
```

Comment: So you've only got problem with the canvas part? It would be a good idea to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some sample data.

Comment: ill edit the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it on my own

```
var i;
        for(i = 0;i < roundedPercent; i++)  {
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.lineWidth = 14
            ctx.strokeStyle = randomColor
            ctx.fillStyle = randomColor
            ctx.arc(203 + (i * 4.32), 190, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
            ctx.stroke()
            ctx.fill()
            //total length of the total bar is 432, so 1% is 4.32.
            //This code basically draws a circle for each percent
            }
```